# Initialize NSPersistentStore object

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swift3

Swift version: swift3.0
target iOS version: 10.0

I try to write unit test for a function which involves core data. So the first things i want to do is initializing class variable with type NSPersistentStore.

here is my code for class variable

```
class DataProviderTests: XCTestCase {
    var storeCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator!
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
    var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel!
    var store: NSPersistentStore!
    .....
}
```

and below is the setup function where initialize the class variables

```
override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()

    managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModelFromBundles(nil)
    storeCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)
    do{
        try store = storeCoordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSInMemoryStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: nil, options: nil)
    }catch let error as NSError{
        print(error)
        store = nil
    }
    .....
}
```

But the problems is that Xcode keeps complaining that the class has no initializer.

```
Swift Compiler Error: Class 'DataProviderTests' has no initializers
```

I found out that 'store' variable is not properly initialized.

However addPersistanteStoreWithtype() function can throws the error, I should use try and catch clause. but it cause this issues..

what is the best way to initialize store class variable such that resolve the issue?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please post which actual error is currently occurring and on which line. Also, please let us know the target iOS version.

Comment: @androisojavaswift - please see my revised answer. Leave comment if you have any questions for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a `try` - `catch` execution that works for me:

```
func getDocumentsURL() -> URL {
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    return documentsURL
}

var modelUrl: URL? // This would be the unique URL for your data model

let storeUrl:URL = getDocumentsURL().appendingPathComponent("<YOURNAME.sqlite>") // Make sure to update with your project name or whatever your sqlite filename is

var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator!

var store: NSPersistentStore!

var error: Error? // Use to handle error in case of failure

if let modelAtUrl = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelUrl) {

     managedObjectModel = modelAtUrl

     persistentStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)

     let options = [
         NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
         NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true
     ]

     managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: concurrencyType)
     managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = persistentStoreCoordinator

     do {
         try store = self.persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSInMemoryStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: storeUrl, options: options)
        } catch let error as Error {
         print("Unable to initialize persistent store coordinator:", error)
         self.error = error
     } catch {
         fatalError()
     }

} else {
     fatalError("Error initializing managed object model from URL: \(modelUrl)")
}
```

Comment: Please check updates if you're trying to use this. I added more explanation for how to properly assign `storeUrl` property, and updated for Swift 3 by using `Error` instead of `NSError`.

Comment: Thank you for the code but what I try to achieve is initializing  class variable, 'var store: NSPersistentStore!', which should be initialized with new store object returned by addPersistentStoreWithType().   In unit test, setup() is the same as init(). Also since it is for testing, I don't actually need to create real store object but I try to create fake one for testing purpose that's why i'm using 'NSInMemoryStoreType' value for store type.

Comment: @androisojavaswift - see updated answer. You can initialize the `store` variable after you say `do{ try store = self.persistentStoreCoordinator`

Comment: @androisojavaswift - also added `NSInMemoryStoreType` to the persistent store type.